# Cocoapods symbols not found for .m file with extern consts

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods

I've got an .m file with some consts in it that I'm trying to include in the source files in a podspec:

```
s.source_files  =     'GBToolbox/GBConstants_Common.{h,m}',
                      ...
```

But when building the app I get a symbols not found error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_kSomeConst", referenced from:
      _DataForObject in APIProxy.o
      ...
```

Where the source files look like, header:

```
//GBConstants_Common.m

extern NSUInteger const kSomeConstant;
```

Implementation:

```
//GBConstants_Common.m

#import "GBConstants_Common.h"

NSUInteger const kSomeConstant = 42;
```

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: What is your target App MAC OSx or IOS device ?

Comment: @tdelepine iOS Device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem one week ago.  Your Pods project dosen't compile all required architectures. Look your message

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
```

For correct this :

- Select your Pods target in Build Setting tab, check if "Build Active Architectures only" all must be set to NO
- Base SDK must be an IOS (Latest IOS (IOS 6.1)
- Architectures must be set $ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT (Standard armv7 armv7s)

The same value must be set in the Pods Project